# How to invoke REST API from OIM event handlers

Tags: oim

I have a  requirement to call external REST API from custom postprocess event handler in OracleIdentityManager?

If anyone have idea,please post here.

Comment: so what is the issue you experience? HttpUrlConnection will help you

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you getting any exception?

Comment: I am getting error at the time of plugin registration.
Oct 29, 2012 12:22:19 PM oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient loginSessionCreated
SEVERE: An error occured while trying to notify server that a new login session has been created.
oracle.iam.platform.utils.NoSuchServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 0):

There is no OIM Rest API  for the invoking  Event Handler as of  now. In future there might  be development for it.